# REACTJS getDOMNode Error on undefined dynamic refs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get a DOM node ref from a dynamic object but I am getting the following error in the Chrome console:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getDOMNode' of undefined.

https://jsfiddle.net/ux4rL8sf/6/

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function () {
      return {
        currentItems : [{"id":"1"} ,  {"id":"2"} , {"id":"3"}]
      };
    },

   onRowClick: function (i) {
     var x;
     if (i == 'abs') {
        x = this.refs[i].getDOMNode().scrollHeight;
     } else {
        x = this.refs['row' + i].getDOMNode().scrollHeight;
     }

     alert(x);

  },

    render: function() {
      var Items = this.state.currentItems.map(function(tv) {
             return (<div refs={"row" + tv.id} onClick={this.onRowClick.bind(this, tv.id)} > {tv.id}</div>);   
     }.bind(this)
  );
       return (<div> {Items} <div ref="abs" onClick={this.onRowClick.bind(this, 'abs')}>Test  </div> </div>) ;
    }
}
);

React.render(<Hello  />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the callback you provide to `map` when creating the `Items` variable in your `render` method, you have

`return (<div refs={...`

I think you want

`return (<div ref={...`

instead.

Answer (score 1):

On line 22 of your fiddle, you use `refs` instead of `ref`. I think that should fix your problem.